# Object Not Responsive With Position: Relative

Tags: html, css

I want a square button to be responsive when the browser is shrunk but it's not moving. What's the problem? Thanks for the help!

```
<div class="firstSection">
        <div class="menuBox"></div>

.firstSection {
    background-image: url(/Users/omaramin/Documents/Competition/project/mainBanner.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    top:-144px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Bariol;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.menuBox {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;  
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Which one is the button? How about a JSFiddle?

Comment: Having the same problem please see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038035/how-to-fix-logo-staying-unresponsive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using pixel-based positioning, use percentage instead.

```
.menuBox {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 200px;  
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did! Thank you so much! I'll give you the green arrow in 7 minutes when I'm allowed to

Comment: @user2605157 Glad I could help! I love green arrows!! :)

Answer (score 0):

use display flex for paret  and rem instead of px.it solved my bug