# How to fix logo staying unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

All the images that are not background images are not becoming responsive!

Tried max-width, images like the logo, mouse cursor are noot responsive

```
<header class=" bg-img bg-image-full">
    <img class = "img-fluid"src="h_img.jpg">
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png" >
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
    <br>
    <h1 style="font-size:49px">WELCOME</h1>
    <h2>TO DELANI STUDIOS</h2>
    <h5>Amazing people are making amazing designs</h5>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="javascript: document.body.scrollIntoView(false);" id=""><img class="mouse" src="mouse_click.png"></a>
</div>
```

This is the css

```
.bg-img {
    background-image: url("hero.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -2100px;
    margin-left: 630px;
    max-width: 5%;
    height: auto !important;
}

.mouse {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1200px;
    margin-left: 670px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Images to be responsive

Comment: This is the css
.bg-img {
  background-image: url("hero.jpg");
   background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
  max-width:100%;
}
.logo{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -2100px;
  margin-left: 630px;

max-width: 5%;
height: auto !important;
}

  .mouse{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1200px;
  margin-left: 670px;
  max-width: 100%;
height: auto !important;
}

Comment: please edit your post to include code

Comment: ???? how do i do that

Comment: someone else already edited it. but underneath your post are three small texts: "share, edit, flag"

Answer (score 0):

Check `object-fit` property for images: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit. However, note that it's not supported by some older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! As it is currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit it and add more details why and how it works. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.